# why the "Use for Development" no appearing for Xcode 6 and iPhone 5 with IOS 8.0

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, provisioning

I'm trying to follow this link get the "Provisioning Profiles" with Xcode, but I can't find the "Use for Development" in Xcode's Organizer window. Can someone help solve it or get around it?
(https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileLanding.action)

basic specs are as in title of the question.

in my Xcode "devices" is shows the IOS 8.1, a newer version, could this be the problem. 
I'm not so willing to update coz it slows down iPhone operation. Is there other anyway to know if this matters?

I have searched all the relevant questions, so please don't say this is not a well researched question. Rookie here.

also, lots of related posts are out of date.

If it's not the reason at all, please help me understand what I need to do.

Comment: Oh I found out how to. the button is not there, but you can use "add manually"

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/OverviewofiTunesConnect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrade your McBook to Yosemite, all these bullshit questions will be gone..